# C++ regex. Get strings with delimiter

Tags: javascript, c++, regex, task, c++14

i'm creating a simple chat with boost asio, std thread and regex.

My chat "protocol" looks like this "***name\0password\0msg\0***" Help me please write a regex which will parse and validate this string.

I need to get from this string: name, password and msg

name is used regex "**\D\w{1,11}**" and password: "**.{1,12}**"

how combine this regex and get name, pass and msg from string

i tried this: "**\D\w{1,11}\0.{1,12}\0.*\0**" but!!! BUT!!! this regex matches all string between begin and last '\0'. How fix that?

Comment: It’s not clear what exactly the problem is. “[T]his regex matches all string[s] between begin and last `\0`” — and… what should it do instead? What did you expect the regex to match? What does any of this even have to do with JavaScript or concurrent threads called “tasks”?

Comment: You don't really need regex for this, you can just loop through until you find a terminator  then take that sub string. I'm typically against regex too just because it's a tricky deal.

Comment: Can you write out this string `"name\0password\0msg\0"` after the language parses it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to put parenthesis to seperate capture groups and then escape the \ as it is a special character in regex.So your expression should look like this:

```
(\D\w{1,11})\\0(.{1,12})\\0(.*)\\0
```

After doing this, the first match will contain 'name',the second will contain 'password' and the third will contain 'message'.